# Twitter API returns all geo information as None/Null

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python

I have a Developer Twitter Elevated account, but every time I get tweets either in streaming or historical, they always come with all the information except geo information (these appear as None using Tweepy, and null in NiFi).

At first I thought it might have to do with some problem with Twitter, but I checked other tweets I fetched 1 year ago with the same developer account and all the geo information came as None too (whereas the rest of the data was there).

I also tried with tweets whose users had the geo location enabled and still no geo data.

What might be the issue?